# How to evaluate string in js as a template

Tags: javascript

I want to do my routing in a central controlled manner, for that I defined some views, and I'd like to evaluate them as if it was a template in the format:

```
`this is a  ${variable} in the template`
```

here's my code:

```
const Views = Object.freeze({
    Home: {path:"/"},
    Kind:{path:"/${kind}", values:{kind:{notNull:true}}},
    SearchEntity:{path:"/${kind}/search/${name}", values:{kind:{notNull:true}, name:{}}},
    Entity:{path:"/${kind}/shop/${eid}", values:{kind:{notNull:true}, eid:{notNull:true}}},
    Issue:{path:"/${kind}/shop/${eid}/issue/${issueId}", values:{kind:{notNull:true}, eid:{notNull:true}, issueId:{notNull:true}}},
    NewShop:{path:"/${kind}/newShop/${name}", values:{kind:{notNull:true}, name:{}}},
})

eval.call({kind:"myKind", eid:"myeid", issueId:"myIssueId"}, Views.Issue.path)
```

this obviously doesn't work, that's why I'm asking the question :)

The context is not understood by the eval method:

```
undefined:1
/${kind}/shop/${eid}/issue/${issueId}
^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
    at Object.eval (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Zied\work\weally\src\util.js:10:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:240:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:564:3)
```

Naturally I could have functions instead of templates and resovle the issue, but i'd like to have a cleaner more readable code, and i want to intervene in the middle with some more controls (like notNull validation checks etc...) in a centralized manner. So I want to keep declarations apart from executions

Comment: naturally I could have functions instead of templates and resovle the issue, but i'd like to have a cleaner more readable code, and i want to intervene in the middle with some more controls (like notNull checks etc...) in a centralized manner. So I want to keep declarations apart from executions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `eval` - have the `path` property be a *function* that returns a template literal instead, and call that function:

```js
const Views = Object.freeze({
  Issue: {
    path: ({kind, eid, issueId }) => `/${kind}/shop/${eid}/issue/${issueId}`,
    values: {
      kind: {
        notNull: true
      },
      eid: {
        notNull: true
      },
      issueId: {
        notNull: true
      }
    }
  },
});
console.log(Views.Issue.path({
  kind: "myKind",
  eid: "myeid",
  issueId: "myIssueId"
}));
```

If you can't put a function in the `path` property, then you could use a regular expression to match `${varName}` in the string and replace it with the same property in the input object:

```js
const Views = Object.freeze({
  Issue: {
    path: '/${kind}/shop/${eid}/issue/${issueId}',
    values: {
      kind: {
        notNull: true
      },
      eid: {
        notNull: true
      },
      issueId: {
        notNull: true
      }
    }
  },
});

const replace = (template, obj) => template.replace(/\${(\w+)}/g, (_, varName) => obj[varName]);
console.log(replace(Views.Issue.path, {
  kind: "myKind",
  eid: "myeid",
  issueId: "myIssueId"
}));
```

If you want to validate as well:

```js
const Views = Object.freeze({
  Issue: {
    path: '/${kind}/shop/${eid}/issue/${issueId}',
    values: {
      kind: {
        notNull: true
      },
      eid: {
        notNull: true
      },
      issueId: {
        notNull: true
      }
    }
  },
});

const replace = (template, conditions, obj) => {
  const required = Object.entries(conditions)
    .filter(([, { notNull }]) => notNull)
    .map(([key]) => key);
  if (!required.every(prop => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))) throw new Error('required missing');
  return template.replace(/\${(\w+)}/g, (_, varName) => obj[varName]);
};


console.log(replace(
  Views.Issue.path,
  Views.Issue.values,
  {
  kind: "myKind",
  eid: "myeid",
  issueId: "myIssueId"
}));


console.log(replace(
  Views.Issue.path,
  Views.Issue.values,
  {
  kind: "myKind",
  eid: "myeid",
}));
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, thanks for the answer, but as I just commented (I expected this type of answer):

naturally I could have functions instead of templates and resovle the issue, but i'd like to have a cleaner more readable code, and i want to intervene in the middle with some more controls (like notNull checks etc...) in a centralized manner. So I want to keep declarations apart from executions

Comment: as you may have noticed, there's a notNull metadata that have to be processed before executing the template, there will come other constraints with centralized behavior

Comment: great answer htanks! 
so there's no simple js way to do it if I understand well? it needs a regexp workaround

Comment: The "simple way to do it" *is* to use the function, but if that's not the case, you'll have to code something a lot more complicated to replace manually.

Comment: I will not tag the answer as correct for the moment, just to let people who have more 'native' solutions answer. If nobody does, I wil assume there's no direct js solution for this need and I'll mark your answer as the good one

Comment: thanks for integrating the validation in your example, that's more work you've done. My issue is really just the templating, the validation will happen in a different function